# Cannot parse list of elements from xml with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

when I try to parse the following XML I get an error with Jackson:

```
<root>
  <aCollection>
    <language xml:lang="en">
      <entry id="1" value="foo"/>
      <entry id="2" value="bar"/>
      <entry id="3" value="blah"/>
    </language>
  </aCollection>
</root>
```

The classes I use are:

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class RootDTO {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "aCollection")
  private CollectionDTO collection;
}

@Data
public class CollectionDTO {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "language")
  LanguageDTO language;
}

@Data
public class LanguageDTO {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "entry")
  EntryDTO[] entries;
}

@Data
public class EntryDTO {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String id;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String value;

}
```

The error is:
`Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.tinkerdesk.viewer.model.DTO.EntryDTO] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method`

If I remove the array brackets it works but of course only parses the first `entry` element. I found that I should maybe use `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` on top of `EntryDTO[] entries;` since the elements are not wrapped. However this does not comile for me because there is no `useWrapping` in the `com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlElementWrapper`.  My Jackson core version is 2.9.6 and xml-databind 0.6.2. Is there now a newer way to do this?

Comment: Hi - what happens if you add a constructor to the DTO class setting the values - I recall this solving it for a json input, not sure if the same for xml

Comment: @RichAckroyd didn't work a constructor that was using two strings (id/value) gets ignored. If I use a single string constructor and put a breakpoint in, I can see it gives me the content of the value attribute, but Jackson then crashes further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I made a stupid error. The 0.6.2 version of Jackson Dataformat Xml should have made me suspicious in the first place. It seems at some point they moved to a new namespace and I was using the old namespace in gradle which sadly resolved to a maven repository that has last been updated in 2011. 
Updating the namespace made it resolve 2.9.5 which has the useWrapping property. Setting this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tom answered, I used old namespace for dependency.

Removed below old dependency from pom.xml

```
<!--<dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId> <version>RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>-->
```

And Added:

```
<dependency><groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
 <version>2.15.2</version>
 </dependency>
```